# How to reference SSM parameter store parameters from within an in-vpc codebuild?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, http-proxy, aws-codebuild

I have an in-vpc codebuild which is set up using an ELB as a proxy server(For limited internet access). The buildspec of that codebuild is referencing a parameter from the parameter store. However, when the build is run, it fails with

`Decrypted Variables Error: RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post https://ssm.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/: dial tcp 52.179.283.42:443: i/o timeout`

The proxy server has access to all amazonaws.com endpoints, all HTTP_PROXY variables setup properly, and in the build spec I have also mentioned the proxy settings. (upload logs/artifcats - true). Not sure how to fix this issue, or if it is allowed to access SSM parameters from invpc codebuild?

Comment: I am facing the same issue..How you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the env variables in your buildspec in small caps as well which the golang programs are genrally looking for:

```
env:
  variables:
    HTTP_PROXY: "http://<proxy_server_hostname>:9480"
    HTTPS_PROXY: "http://<proxy_server_hostname>:9480"
    NO_PROXY: "169.254.169.254,169.254.170.2"
    http_proxy: "http://<proxy_server_hostname>:9480"
    https_proxy: "http://<proxy_server_hostname>:9480"
    no_proxy: "169.254.169.254,169.254.170.2"
build:
    commands:
      - curl -v https://ssm.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That did not work though, it failed with the same error. From the docs it says it might be an ssl bump issue, but I have another invpc codebuild job which is able to upload logs and works properly(only difference is that it does not have ssm referenced params in buildspec)

Comment: The error suggests the CLI is trying to connect directly to SSM Endpoint instead of going through proxy.

Comment: Is SSM VPC Endpoint an option you can use? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-systems-manager-vpc-endpoints/